# Tags synonyms for rewards

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

[block-reward](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/block-reward) and [mining-reward](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mining-reward) have the same description and seem very close to me.

Shouldn't they be made synonyms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great suggestion! I went ahead and created the synonym and merged them. Since [mining-reward](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mining-reward) had only been used once so far I set [block-reward](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/block-reward) as the master synonym.